# Set Caret Position In AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

How to set caret position in AngularJS using directive.
Requirment :

1) Input field (ng-model).

2) User Scan through bar code reader.

3) Value set In Input field.

4) After user hit enter input field cleared.

5) But the position of cursor should be set to this input only.

How to do 5th Point using Directive.

Comment: can you show some code?

Comment: you want to set the focus back to the input field from some other control?